# Как реализовать нажатие клавиш Ctrl и Shift на языке С/C++

Tags: c++, c, консоль

Задание звучит так:

> Написать программу, которая выводит в заданную позицию консоли
>   информацию про координаты мыши, состояние управляющих клавиш (ALT,
>   CTRL, SHIFT), скан-код и ASCII-код нажатой клавиши. Для вывода
>   результатов использовать функции *SetConsoleCursorPosition,(),
>   wsprintf(), WriteConsole()*.

Перечитал [документацию](http://www.cyberguru.ru/win32/win32-keyboard.html?showall=1), посмотрел примеры (последний слишком сумбурный). Так как клавиши символьные, то для их написания придется использовать ещё функцию `TranslateMessage`.

Вопрос по реализации нажатия клавиш, каким образом лучше поступить. (Выделил блок кода, по которому вопрос).

На данный момент имею такой код:

```
        #include "stdafx.h"
        #include <cstring>
        #include <iostream>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <conio.h>
        #include <windows.h>
        #include <winuser.h>


        #define  STR_SIZE 256
        #define BUFSIZE 65535
        #define SHIFTED 0x8000


        int main() {

            setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
            HANDLE hIn, hOut;
            DWORD size = STR_SIZE;
            char result[STR_SIZE];

            FreeConsole();
            AllocConsole();
            SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

            hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
            hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

            GetDC(NULL); // дескриптор стола
            POINT p; // структура для координат
            COORD cord; // структура COORD, которая указывает позицию курсора

            cord.X = 0; // координата X структуры COORD
            cord.Y = 0; // координата Y структуры COORD

   //------------------------------------------------------------------


            HWND hwndMain;
            HACCEL haccl;
            UINT uMsg;
            UINT wParam;
            LONG lParam;
            HWND hwnd;
            MSG msg;

                    switch (wParam)
                    {
                    case 0x10:

                             /*SHIFT key.*/
                        printf("SHIFT pressed", wParam);

                            break;

                    case 0x11:

                             /*CTRL key.*/
                        printf("CTRL pressed", wParam);

                            break;
                    case 0x12:

                             /*ALT key. */
                        printf("ALT pressed", wParam);

                            break;
                    default:

                        printf("OTHER pressed", wParam);
                             /* Обработка воспроизводимых символов. */

                            break;
                    }

                    while (GetMessage(&msg, (HWND)NULL, 0, 0))
                    {
                        if (TranslateAccelerator(hwndMain, haccl, &msg) == 0)
                        {
                            TranslateMessage(&msg);
                            DispatchMessage(&msg);
                        }
                    }   
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            while (1) {
                wsprintf(result, "Позиция курсора: ");
                WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);
                GetCursorPos(&p);
                wsprintf(result, "x = %4ld, y = %4ld\r\n", p.x, p.y);
                WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cord);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

UPD:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

VOID ErrorExit(LPCSTR);
VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD);
VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD);

#define  STR_SIZE 256
#define BUFSIZE 65535
#define SHIFTED 0x8000

HANDLE hStdin;
HANDLE hOut;
DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;

DWORD scan = 0; //скан-код последней клавиши
wchar_t code = 0; //код символа последней клавиши
bool alt, ctrl, shift; //состояние управляющих клавиш

void PrintData() {
    DWORD size = STR_SIZE;
    char result[STR_SIZE];

    //GetDC(NULL); // дескриптор стола
    POINT p; // структура для координат
    COORD cord; // структура COORD, которая указывает позицию курсора

    cord.X = 0; // координата X структуры COORD
    cord.Y = 0; // координата Y структуры COORD

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cord);
    wsprintf(result, "Позиция курсора: ");
    WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    wsprintf(result, "x = %4ld, y = %4ld\r\n", p.x, p.y);
    WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

    if (scan != 0) {
        wsprintf(result, "Последняя нажатая клавиша\nScan code: %4u\r\n", (UINT)scan);
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        wsprintf(result, "Character code: %4u\r\n", (UINT)code);
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);


        if (ctrl) wsprintf(result, "CTRL:(+) "); else  wsprintf(result, "CTRL:(-) ");
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        if (shift) wsprintf(result, "SHIFT:(+) "); else  wsprintf(result, "SHIFT:(-) ");
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        if (alt) wsprintf(result, "ALT:(+) "); else  wsprintf(result, "ALT:(-) ");
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, strlen(result), nullptr, nullptr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];

    // Get the standard input handle. 

    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Save the current input mode, to be restored on exit. 

    if (!GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode))
        ErrorExit("GetConsoleMode");

    // Enable the window and mouse input events. 

    fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode))
        ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");

    // Loop to read and handle input events. 

    while (1)
    {
        // Wait for the events. 

        if (!ReadConsoleInput(
            hStdin,      // input buffer handle 
            irInBuf,     // buffer to read into 
            128,         // size of read buffer 
            &cNumRead)) // number of records read 
            ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput");

        // Dispatch the events to the appropriate handler. 

        for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++)
        {
            switch (irInBuf[i].EventType)
            {
            case KEY_EVENT: // keyboard input 
                KeyEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent);
                break;

            case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input 
                MouseEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent);
                break;

            case WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT:
            case FOCUS_EVENT:
            case MENU_EVENT:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Restore input mode on exit.

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    return 0;
}


VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker)
{

    if (ker.bKeyDown) {
        scan = ker.wVirtualScanCode;
        code = ker.uChar.UnicodeChar;

        if ((ker.dwControlKeyState & SHIFT_PRESSED) > 0) shift = true; else shift = false;

        if ((ker.dwControlKeyState & LEFT_ALT_PRESSED) > 0 ||
            (ker.dwControlKeyState & RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED) > 0) alt = true;
        else alt = false;

        if ((ker.dwControlKeyState & LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED) > 0 ||
            (ker.dwControlKeyState & RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED) > 0) ctrl = true;
        else ctrl = false;

        PrintData();
    }

}

VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mer)
{
    if (mer.dwEventFlags == MOUSE_MOVED) {
        PrintData();
    }
}

VOID ErrorExit(LPCSTR lpszMessage)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lpszMessage);

    // Restore input mode on exit.
    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Comment: Вообще, в консоли с мышью совсем по другому работают. Там своя обработка событий есть. И с клавишами точно так же. События включаются функциями `GetConsoleMode` и `SetConsoleMode`. Считываются функцией `ReadConsoleInput`. Туда же и события мыши приходят, если их включить. А вовсе не через оконный `GetMessage` это всё делается. Можно [вот здесь](https://github.com/kisssko/tglaa_static/blob/master/sysio.c) пример глянуть.

Comment: @kisssko, буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Система отправляет события клавиатуры для консольных приложений не в процесс консольного приложения, а в системный процесс, владеющий окном консоли (csrss или conhost в зависимости от ОС), создавать цикл обработки сообщений бесполезно. Чтобы обрабатывать такие события, нужно использовать специальные функции работы с консольным вводом:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

VOID ErrorExit(LPSTR);
VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD); 
VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD);

#define  STR_SIZE 256
#define BUFSIZE 65535
#define SHIFTED 0x8000

HANDLE hStdin; 
HANDLE hOut;
DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;

DWORD scan=0; //скан-код последней клавиши
wchar_t code=0; //код символа последней клавиши
bool alt,ctrl,shift; //состояние управляющих клавиш

void PrintData(){

    DWORD size = STR_SIZE;
    TCHAR result[STR_SIZE];         

    POINT p; // структура для координат
    COORD cord; // структура COORD, которая указывает позицию курсора

    cord.X = 0; // координата X структуры COORD
    cord.Y = 0; // координата Y структуры COORD

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cord);
    wsprintf(result, L"Позиция курсора: ");
    WriteConsole(hOut, result, wcslen(result), nullptr, nullptr);
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    wsprintf(result, L"x = %4ld, y = %4ld\r\n", p.x, p.y);
    WriteConsole(hOut, result, wcslen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        if(scan!=0){
        wsprintf(result, L"Последняя нажатая клавиша\nScan code: %4u, Character code: %4u\r\n", (UINT)scan,(UINT)code);
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, wcslen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        if(ctrl) wsprintf(result,L"CTRL:(+) "); else  wsprintf(result,L"CTRL:(-) ");
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, wcslen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        if(shift) wsprintf(result,L"SHIFT:(+) "); else  wsprintf(result,L"SHIFT:(-) ");
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, wcslen(result), nullptr, nullptr);

        if(alt) wsprintf(result,L"ALT:(+) "); else  wsprintf(result,L"ALT:(-) ");
        WriteConsole(hOut, result, wcslen(result), nullptr, nullptr);
        }     

}


int main() 
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i; 
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];         

    // Get the standard input handle. 

    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Save the current input mode, to be restored on exit. 

    if (! GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode) ) 
        ErrorExit("GetConsoleMode"); 

    // Enable the window and mouse input events. 

    fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT; 
    if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode) ) 
        ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode"); 

    // Loop to read and handle input events. 

    while (1) 
    { 
        // Wait for the events. 

        if (! ReadConsoleInput( 
                hStdin,      // input buffer handle 
                irInBuf,     // buffer to read into 
                128,         // size of read buffer 
                &cNumRead) ) // number of records read 
            ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput"); 

        // Dispatch the events to the appropriate handler. 

        for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++) 
        {
            switch(irInBuf[i].EventType) 
            { 
                case KEY_EVENT: // keyboard input 
                    KeyEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent); 
                    break; 

                case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input 
                    MouseEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent); 
                    break; 

                case WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT: 
                case FOCUS_EVENT: 
                case MENU_EVENT:   
                    break;                 
            } 
        }
    } 

    // Restore input mode on exit.

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    return 0; 
}


VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker)
{   

    if(ker.bKeyDown){
        scan=ker.wVirtualScanCode;
        code=ker.uChar.UnicodeChar;

        if((ker.dwControlKeyState & SHIFT_PRESSED) > 0) shift=true; else shift=false;

        if((ker.dwControlKeyState & LEFT_ALT_PRESSED) > 0 || 
            (ker.dwControlKeyState & RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED) > 0) alt=true; 
        else alt=false;

        if((ker.dwControlKeyState & LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED) > 0 || 
            (ker.dwControlKeyState & RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED) > 0) ctrl=true; 
        else ctrl=false;

        PrintData();
    }

}

VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mer)
{
    if(mer.dwEventFlags == MOUSE_MOVED){
        PrintData();
    }    
}

VOID ErrorExit (LPSTR lpszMessage) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lpszMessage); 

    // Restore input mode on exit.
    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwSaveOldMode);

    ExitProcess(0); 
}
```

[Reading Input Buffer Events - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events)